# rxjs, call next on generator only after previous operation completes

Tags: iterator, generator, rxjs5

I'm uploading a file by creating slices of file using [Blob.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/slice) in a [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) function

```ts
export function* chunkFile(file: File, chunkSize: number) {
    let chunkStart = 0;
    const _chunkEnd = chunkStart + chunkSize;
    let chunkEnd = _chunkEnd > file.size ? file.size : _chunkEnd;
    while (chunkStart < file.size) {
        yield <ChunkType>{
            chunk: file.slice(chunkStart, chunkEnd),
            start: chunkStart,
            end: chunkEnd
        };
        chunkStart = chunkEnd;
        const _chunkEndIn = chunkStart + chunkSize;
        chunkEnd = _chunkEndIn > file.size ? file.size : _chunkEndIn;
    }
}
```

and I'm uploading file like this

```ts
Observable.from(chunckFile(file,chunkSize)).concatMap(uploadRoutine).subscribe();
```

But all chunks are created at same time.

what I need is create new chunck (call `next` on generator) only when current chunk upload completes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found Solution by my own

```ts
export function rxIterable<T, R>(source: Iterator<T>, consumer: (value: T) => Observable<R>) {
    const first = source.next();
    if (first.done) {
        return empty<R>();
    }
    return consumer(first.value).pipe(
        expand(() => {
            const next = source.next();
            if (next.done) {
                return empty<R>();
            }
            return consumer(next.value);
        }),
        finalize(() => source.return())
    );
}
```